# Qt: How to integrate QMLQuick and C++ ? Where can I find "project file"?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtquick2

Of course I have documentation:

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-topic.html

Unfortunately, it is not clearly enought for me:

```
CONFIG += qmltypes
QML_IMPORT_NAME = io.qt.examples.backend
QML_IMPORT_MAJOR_VERSION = 1
```

There is written: "Add the following lines to your project file:"

What does the "project file" mean? I guess it is .pro file.
Why this file project does not existing on my Cmake list?
Do I have to create this file on my own? How to do this?

I was searching .pro file, but I cannot find it in my project.
I couldn't find, where can I create such file.
I also have tried to paste code above into cMake list - but it is not that.

I have also watched a few tutorials, where is shown how to integrate QML and C++, and I am confused cause it looks like there are a few opportunities to solve this.
It seems to me, some people skipping such things as adding .h and .cpp files to cMake list.

I am also expecting if you explain me please, which way for connecting Qml and C++ I have to choose.
Of course if it is not that way in link I attached above.
I need universal solution, most common for most of Qt Quick applications.

Comment: You're mixing two different build systems: cmake and qmake. You only need a .pro file if you're using qmake. As of Qt6, Qt recommends moving to cmake, but they still support qmake.

Comment: Thanks! It is important to notice what you saying. Exactly, Qt recomends using Cmake and I confused this with qmake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use CMake you should use `qt_add_qml_module()`. Here is the content of the CMakeLists.txt which I've used together with the backend.cpp/.h from your link above.

To include that in QML use `import untitledStackoverflow`.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)

project(untitledStackoverflow VERSION 0.1 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)

find_package(Qt6 6.2 COMPONENTS Quick REQUIRED)

qt_add_executable(appuntitledStackoverflow
    backend.cpp backend.h
    main.cpp
)

qt_add_qml_module(appuntitledStackoverflow
    URI untitledStackoverflow
    VERSION 1.0
    QML_FILES main.qml
)

target_link_libraries(appuntitledStackoverflow
    PRIVATE Qt6::Quick)
```

Comment: It should be noted that this answer is specific to Qt6. The OP doesn't specify exactly, but links to documentation from Qt5.

Comment: Okay! Thanks! You are right, I linked to Qt 5 documentation and was watching Qt 5 tutorial. Sorry. Since Qt 6 it became easier. Thanks for your help.